# Which packages of Gapps can't be downloaded through the Play Store/marketplace?

Tags: google-play-store, custom-roms, google-apps, gapps

I've seen that there are quite many different modular packages of the Gapps http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2397942 and I was wondering if I can install the nano and add the other Gapps one by one through the Play Store. Or if there by chance some Google apps that can't be retrieved with the Play Store?

I'd like to start with a very minimal set of apps if possible (and not to install Google Now).

Comment: The Open Gapps project has [a comprehensive wiki](https://github.com/opengapps/opengapps/wiki/Package-Comparison) on which packages have their corresponding Play Store entry, but AFAIK not all apps can be downloaded if they are not installed by Gapps in the first place (e.g. Google Camera). Might need to recheck some time later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I'm pretty sure all of the other 'Google Apps' can be requested from the Play Store. I myself, also usually start the basis of a new ROM installation with the Nano-gapps package.

It removes a lot of the non-mandatory Google bloatware such as GoogleNow, PlayMusic (I use an alternative) and even Gmail (I have my Gmail emails come through the stock Email app to avoid duplication).

Comment: It seems like to be true based on my flashing experience here